# BASH associative array rearrange keys

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting, hashing, array

I am running into a weird issue with associative arrays in bash.

I have the following files in a directory:

```
ls -lart
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 4096 Feb  9 11:14 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3275 Feb  9 14:16 1.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3275 Feb  9 14:16 2.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3275 Feb  9 14:16 3.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Feb 12 15:19 a.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Feb 12 15:19 123.txt
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Feb 12 15:19 .
```

The files are listed from the oldest to the newest.

-Sent the output of ls -lart to a file with the following command:

```
ls -lart --block-size=K /test |grep txt |awk '{print $9,$5}'  > /tmp/filestodel.txt
```

filestodel.txt has the list of files (with associated size) with from the oldest to the newest:

```
   cat /tmp/filestodel.txt
    1.txt 4K
    2.txt 4K
    3.txt 4K
    a.txt 0K
    123.txt 0K
```

where the first column has the name of the file and the second the size (in Kbytes)

-I define an array and push these entries into it:

```
declare -A cleanup
while read line
    do
    filetodelname=$(echo $line | awk {'print$1'});
    filetodelsize=$(echo $line | awk {'print$2'});
    cleanup[$filetodelname]=$filetodelsize
    done < /tmp/filestodel.txt
```

the idea is to delete files listed in th array from the oldest (first) to the newest, which would translate in starting to delete file 1.txt as per ls -lart output above.

The issue is that when I loop through the keys:

```
for K in "${!cleanup[@]}"; do echo $K; done   #print filenames
```

I get this output:

```
2.txt
3.txt
123.txt
1.txt
a.txt
```

which is clearly messed up!

How I can keep the original order of files in the array?

Thanks,
dom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need 2 arrays, index them by a number in the first pass: first will receive names, second - sizes; then index them by a number (from 0 to number_of_files - 1) again in the second pass, when doing the deletions.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, indeed I thought about that too and eventually will follow it, but I don't understand why the keys were sorted in that bizarre way. It looks like a bug, but I'm sure there is a better explanation.

Comment: It is not bizarre. Almost in every language I know of keys in the dictionaries are out of order. This way it is easier to implement.